# Design NFA, for the binary strings, which accepts even length of string over the Σ={0,1}

Tags: automata, computation

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fdOh5.jpg)

I tried this but this is DFA how would NFA be?

Answer (score 2):

By most definitions, every DFA is also an NFA. So your automaton is an NFA.

If you really want some nondeterminism, here is another NFA:

```
              0,1
-> ((even))  <--->  (odd)
      ^
      | 0,1
      v
  (also odd)
```

As you can see, forcing an automaton to use nondeterminism is not very enlightening.

In most cases, using nondeterminism makes the automaton more compact and simple to write. But in this case the automaton already only used two states. It can hardly get smaller.